# How to extract value from JSON object in React?

Tags: json, reactjs, es6-promise

I have a case where my JSON object needs remapping first e.g. from
`{ name: goals, value: 65 } to { goals: 65}`. I believe I achieved that with reduce in getStats function (see screenshot from the console)

However I want to wrap it in a function i.e. `getData(name){}`
where I will be passing `name = 'goals'` and get the specific value 65

How to achieve that and simplify my code?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your title has **nothing** to do with your question, please update it to a proper title instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans happy to do that, how would you name it?

Comment: What is your actual question, summarized in a single sentence? That should be your post title. For instance, there is no such thing as a "JSON object", JSON data is string data. There are objects in JavaScript, which are part of basic JS syntax, so "React" is not important for accessing an object property. If you want to write a function that accesses a property in an object based on another property match, then just write a function to do that, there is still no involved by React, specifically, there. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Create simple `getData` function which returns value for key.

```
getData(key, defaultValue = '') {
    // I suggest to cache result of next call (invalidate cache when needed)
    const data = this.getStats(playerStats);
    return data[key] || defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, really neat, but how do I render that value tried { getData('goals') } but throws an error

Comment: ...error  ` Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getData is not defined at PlayerList.render` and whole list of other at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper...  PlayerList being => export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlayerList);

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/maciejk77/player-card/blob/version-B/src/containers/player_list.js

Comment: do this `{this.getData('goals')}`

Comment: right.... but still no joy, throws an error `bundle.js:24363 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: playerStats is not defined`

Comment: I hoped you could adjust code to your needs, since you haven't provided sufficient code sample. Change line 29 to `const data = this.getStats(this.props.stats);`

Comment: this still does not work, I thought I provided a link to the code repo above. It is clean and thanks for your input but I am getting an error stil